# Geoalchemy2 && support for ST_MakeEnvelope

Tags: postgis, geoalchemy-2

I have this working query:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table.the_geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(-75.97464419082118,39.523869271308314,-72.18532985820512,41.552541030492364);
```

and this is my (incorrect) attempt to recreate it with geoalchemy:

```
class ST_MakeEnvelope(GenericFunction):
    name = 'ST_MakeEnvelope'
    type = Geometry

box = "-75.97464419082118,39.523869271308314,-72.18532985820512,41.552541030492364"

results = my_table.query.filter(my_table.the_geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(box)).first()
```

gives me this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) argument of AND must be type boolean, not type geometry

I have not seen any documentation on how you can use the `&&` operator.  Is this possible? I really just need to execute the `ST_MakeEnvelope` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are doing

```
 filter(expr1, expr2)
```

you are telling SQLAlchemy to join the two expressions with an `AND` (see [Query#filter](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter)). That's why you are getting the error message.

Regarding the operator `&&`, it can be used with function [intersects](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spatial_operators.html#geoalchemy2.comparator.BaseComparator.intersects):

```
MyModel.geom.intersects(other_geom)
```

Besides, there is a small issue with `ST_MakeEnvelope`, the coordinates should not be a string:

```
box = [-75.97464419082118,39.523869271308314,-72.18532985820512,41.552541030492364]
... .filter(my_table.the_geom.intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(*box)))
```